# Overwriting and custom inits in objective-c

Tags: ios, initialization, overwrite

I have a class that inherits the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I'm trying to rewrite the `init` method so that I don't have to repeat code for every other `-initWithSomething` function. For a custom initWithSomething method this will work. But I can't figure how to make it work for inherited iniWithSomething methods

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        // This is code I don't want to repeat in initWithSomething methods
        [self startWithHiddenControls];

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                      object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(UIApplicationDidBecomeActive)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL
{

    // Not overwriting doesn't use my overwriten init so i must do it.
    // But how ?!?
    // why [super init] makes inifinite loop? (I know the norm is [super <same method>])
    if(self = [self init]){} // this will not work. Inifinite loop I believe.

    return self;
}

//This method works fine
- (instancetype)initWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)settings
{
    // [self init] works here but HOW?
    if(self = [self init]){
        //my custom stuff
    }
}
```

During writin this post I found that `[super init]` calls the `-(instancetype)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL` and there lies the infinite loop problem. Why the designated initializer `init` calls the secondary initializer `initWithURL`? Should it not be the other way around? Please explain.

Does this mean I should put my code, that I don't want repeated, in the `initWithURL` method instead of the `init` method.

Edit: And that is what I did. I entered the code in the initWithURL method. Now both the default init and my custom init will run it.

Comment: Well, you can't rely on init sequence, only people who developed this class would know why is it that way. My only guess is that basic init triggers initialization with url being nil, that might be needed for proper player state handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you call `init` a designated initializer? I believe, it is not. Let's refer to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3):

> The designated initializer plays an important role for a class. It
>   ensures that inherited instance variables are initialized by invoking
>   the designated initializer of the superclass. **It is typically the
>   init... method that has the most parameters and that does most of the
>   initialization work, and it is the initializer that secondary
>   initializers of the class invoke with messages to self.**

So it doesn't seem to satisfy both characteristic: it has the least number of parameters and apparently it calls another initializer (`initWithContentURL`) with `self`. So, I believe, if you found the real designated initializer, everything would work as expected.

According to the [MPMoviePlayerViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/index.html), the designated initializer is `initWithContentURL`. So you can simply override it instead of `init`.

Comment: Yes it say **typically** it is `init` which doesn't mean always. Thank you. I didn't know or see that in the class reference you could see which was the designated initializer.

Comment: @h3dkandi, yes, indeed, you're right. In fact, I also often make `init` a designated initializer in my classes. By the way, you can specifically declare some `init` method as a designated initialized using a `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER ` macro. More about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW8)

Comment: @h3dkandi, I re-read my answer, and decided, that you're right, I wrote it the wrong way. It's not a requirement. I'll edit it a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a private method and put your common code there, like

```
- (void)commonInitialization {
    [self startWithHiddenControls];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(UIApplicationDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

and then use in your inits:

```
- (instancetype)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL {
    self = [super initWithContentURL:contentURL];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInitialization];
        // everything else
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yes I figured that much. However I didn't want to put the common code in each and every init. I wanted to put it in the default init that is called bye every other type of initialization without having to override it or insert it there.